# Is it possible to get the database.yml file from within an rails engine configuration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am in the process of creating a rails mountable engine and I need to retrieve the database.yml file from the application that is using the engine from within the lib/MyEngine/engine.rb file. First of all is this even possible? And if so how would you achieve this?

I have tried using "Rails.root" from within the engine.rb file but it returns nil.

Any help on this would be great and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be enough this:

```
path = Dir.pwd + '/config/database.yml'
```

Comment: This works perfectly - just one minor amend:-

path = Dir.pwd + '/config/database.yml'

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
path = "#{ENV["APP_ROOT"]}/config/database.yml"
```

If you want to load it already parsed:

```
YAML.load_file("#{ENV["APP_ROOT"]}/config/database.yml")
```

Also, to be sure you get the APP_ROOT variable set up I use to add before those lines:

```
ENV["APP_ROOT"] ||= File.expand_path("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/..")
```

(obv. fix that path depending on how many level you should go back to reach the root folder)

Answer (score 0):

```
File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'database.yml')
```

This will also work on OS other than MacOSX, linux, unix where '/' is not standard delimiter for path.